# Recommended photography magazines

Tags: tips, learning, inspiration

What are some internationally available magazines on photography that you would recommend to a photographer who's mastered the basics and is interested in widening his horizons, in terms of inspiration and technique?
Personally, I'm looking for something that does **not** focus on post-production or aquiring expensive gear.

Comment: Good question... we've had lists of podcasts and books but not yet of magazines.  I'm going to flag this for community wiki, folks should probably post one response per answer.

Comment: "...not focus on ... expensive gear" - Excellent!  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree w/Staale, and to add to that, avoid any magazine that devotes an inordinate amount of space to gear reviews and advertising... well maybe keep one gear one around cuz they're fun to read :)  But for mags that I actually derive inspiration:

- [photo technique](http://www.phototechmag.com/): great photography, great tutorials and very informative in both inspiration and actual technique
- [Aperture](http://www.aperture.org/magazine): More of an 'inspiration' entry, its all photographs and artist's discussion on what they're doing and why
- [B&W](http://www.bandwmag.com/): Similar to Aperture but focusing solely on B&W

Answer (score 6):

The canonical answer would be "any photography magazine that doesn't have the word 'digital' in its title". That said, I have found the British magazines "Digital SLR User" and "Digital SLR photography" to be rather good. Either one, not both; they are rather similar.

Answer (score 4):

I quite enjoy [Nature Photographer](http://www.naturephotographermag.com/) and [Outdoor Photography Canada](http://www.outdoorphotographycanada.com/). The former for it's all-about-nature approach, and the latter for being all-about-Canada. Both do some equipment reviews and the like, but place more emphasis on techniques and photography expeditions. I jump on these whenever there is a new issue.

I also like [Shutterbug](http://www.shutterbug.com/) for it's broader focus. Reviews and news feature more heavily here - as do the ads...

Answer (score 3):

The two magazines I renew my subscription on are [Outdoor Photographer](http://www.outdoorphotographer.com/) and [American Photo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00007AV7N). Both have some very nice articles and interviews, with occasional technical discussions and gear reviews.

Answer (score 3):

UK magazine [Practical Photography](http://www.greatmagazines.co.uk/store/displayitem.asp?sid=322&id=42697&os=Y) is a close fit to your criteria: the articles focus on in-camera technique and they have a sister magazine dedicated to digital techniques which ensures a good separation of content.

Comment: The identically named US publication however is just a bunch of thinly disguised advertorials for camera and lens manufacturers.

Answer (score 2):

I have enjoyed [Photography Monthly](http://www.photographymonthly.com/).

(More than the magazine, I like their [podcast](http://www.photographymonthly.com/videos-and-podcasts)).

Answer (score 2):

I subscribe to the [British Journal of Photography](http://www.bjp-online.com/).

It is more about the business, politics and experience of practising photography professionally than about technique, but I find it useful to understand what's going on in the wider photographic world, to be inspired and to understand where professionals are coming from.

(I realise this one isn't a good answer to your question, but I hope it adds a different slant which may be of interest to some).

Comment: The BJP is usually interesting and to the point. The 'interview' about the Pentak K-01 is a great example of how to cut through manufacturer's BS... http://www.bjp-online.com/british-journal-of-photography/news/2143551/pentax-unveils-compact-01-mirrorless-camera

Answer (score 2):

i love reading **[Better Photography](http://betterphotography.in/)**,,

I can say that this is the best Photography Magazine **based in India**..

It gives tips on improving the skills and also showcase the work of the readers and also the expert's assignment on different projects.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i purchased several magazines which i will like to recommend

Super basic (Intro)

1) Getting Started in Ditigal SLR Photography (Improve your phot skills and take better pictures) by MAGBOOK - UK magazine - ard 4-5 pound

2) The Essential guide to Portraits (Improve your photo skills & take your best ever images) - by MAGBOOK - UK magazine - ard 4-5 pound

Monthly Issue

3) Practical Photograph - www.photoanswers.co.uk - 4 pounds

4) Photoplus (Canon edition) also 4 pound - but i will strongly recommend this as it comes with a DVD *5hr !!! (not sure if it is a monthly bonus DVD intact)

any other magazines that i have magazines that i have missed out or ones that you enjoy reading?

cheers!