# What are the recommended photography magazines from the digital newsstand?

Tags: tips, learning, tablet, apps

The Kindles, iPad, Nooks and other tablets are popularizing the digital medium for reading magazines. To this end, I wanted to extend the general question on [recommended photography magazines](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/7725/1977) to the digital versions.

I understand that many of the recommendations could overlap. However, getting to know the advantages and limitations of the digital medium would be helpful in this regard (formatting, layout, content differences, delivery timing etc).

Also, considering that lots of content is already available for free in the digital medium (most of the articles could be available online free of charge for ex., and apps like flipboard are excellent to consume such content on tablets), does it make sense to subscribe to a digital magazine?

**P.S.** May be a good idea to convert this to a CW once we know the advantages\disadvantages of digital magazines.

Comment: Generally speaking, we try to avoid questions like this...which boils down to a survey. PhotoSE is a question and answer site, and this is an open-ended survey that could never end, and will likely garner rather subjective responses that can never really be qualified. I think this is a solid candidate for closure according to the rules for StackExchange, and our own [FAQ](http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @jrista Since there are some similar questions on books & magazines, would it be better to merge it with one of the existing ones, as this area has not been covered in those questions?

Comment: Probably. It might also be best to close those questions. I'll see if there are any meta discussions about it, and revive them or start something new.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the following two magazines:

**Popular Photography** 
 -Very nice layout, especially on the iPad 
-very good content

**Light it Magazine**: 

-The layout is good, but it's not perfectly fit to the iPad.
 The Content on the other Hand is just great, especially if you are into lighting your images with flash.

Comment: Light it also has embedded video, which could add another dimension.  Do other mags also have video?

Comment: I think most would be able to implement video, but Light it has an advantage because they have so much experience with video production.

Answer (score 0):

Professional Imagemaker have just released their magazine on to Apple's Newsstand on iOS. If you download the app now there is a free issue included.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/professional-imagemaker/id489811498?mt=8